# C# output to Excel spreadsheet, using Excel 2000+

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing a program that reads a text file, extracts information, and outputs it to a template Excel spreadsheet that already exists.

I've managed to do this on my computer using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference and its related methods, and it works fine. I have Excel 2010. However the computers that this program will be used on mostly have either Excel 2000 or Excel 2003, and it won't work on them.

Does anyone know a way to make a program target all versions of Excel from 2000 upwards?

Cheers,

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your needs are simple and you don't have $900 for Aspose.Cells to throw around, you can do any of the following:

- Use NPOI to read, inject data into, and export your template.
- Create a basic HTML file with a table and just named it `*.xls`. You can save your template in Excel as HTML and replace bits and pieces to insert your data.
- Create an XML file using Office 2002/2003 XML format, it's pretty straightforward (caveat: can't be read in Excel 2000). As above, you can save your template in XML Spreadsheet format, read it in, and do some simple stuff to inject your data.

Comment: Thanks. I have done this using NPOI and it seems to be working. I also had a look at the XML idea, it looks like it would be cumbersome to figure out but I will maybe do this if NPOI has any problems on other machines. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You really need to target 2000 or under. 2010 and 2003 will open a 2000 format document whereas 2000 will not open a 2010 document. Office has a single format for 97-2000 and that's what you need to create to make everybody happy.

Interop depends on the version you have installed and I personally have dodged using interop due to its "unmanaged" nature (and it seems to love file locks).

If you want hassle free and extremely fast/powerful creation of Excel documents, you really can not do better than **Aspose.Cells** in my opinion.

[Find it here.](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx)